# help with pointers and passing linked list as parameter, undefined reference c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, undefined-reference

I am getting an error message that says undefined reference to

```
encrypt(int, std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >*)
```

Here is how I am trying to use it:

```
decka = new list<int>;
  ifstream inF;

  inF.open(filename.c_str());

  if (inF.fail()){
    cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  int deckcount = 28;
  int card;
  for(int i = 0; i != deckcount; i++){
    inF >> card;

    decka->push_back(card);
  }
  inF.close();

  if(eorD == "e")
    convertM(message);
    int esize = message.length();
    convertToNum(message);
    encrypt(esize, decka);
}
```

The error is coming from where I try and call encrypt.

Here is the encrypt function:

```
void encrypt(int msize, list<int> *L){

  int jokeA = 27;
  int jokeB = 28;

  list<int>::iterator a = std::find(L->begin(), L->end(), jokeA);
  list<int>::iterator new_position = a;
  for(int i=0; i < 1 && new_position != L->begin(); i++)
    new_position--;

  L->insert(new_position, 1, *a);

  L->erase(a);
}
```

And just so you can see how the class is defined here:

```
class DeckOps{
 public:
  DeckOps(string, string, string);
  ~DeckOps();
  string convertM(string);
  string convertToNum(string);
  void encrypt(int, list<int>*);

 private:

  list<int> *decka;

};
```

My goal here is to be able to access elements of decka using my encrypt function.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with this code. What exactly is the line the error occurs?

Comment: Was the encrypt function defined like you have it here, without DeckOps::?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void encrypt(int msize, list<int> *L){
```

Should be:

```
void DeckOps::encrypt(int msize, list<int> *L){
```

Comment: omg i am lame, i cant believe i did not see that! i guess im thinking a little too hard!